# Symfony: непонятные ошибки при запуске

Tags: symfony, php, symfony2

Развернул с помощью композера *symfony 2*, ничего в самих файлах не менял (разве что роутинг добавился), пытаюсь достучаться до *app.php* или *app_dev.php* - скрипт виснет на *30 секунд* и падает, сначала выдавалось RuntimeErrorException (или что-то похожее) с сообщением о превышении лимита, после добавления `set\_time\_limit(0)` *nginx* стал возвращать `502` через те же тридцать секунд (max_execution_time, request_terminate_timeout = 0).

`~$ top` при этом показывает загрузку одного ядра процессора на *100%* процессом php-fpm. Попытка запустить через апач и mod_php привела к тому, что система начала виснуть, и в топе обнаружился уже kswapd с загрузкой ядра 100% (free при этом показал почти нулевую доступную память). [web]/config.php говорит, что все ок.

Что это за рогатая тварь и как ее лечить?

Запускаю на ноуте, винт ssd, проц не топовый, но до этого не было ни разу, чтобы он с нагрузкой не справлялся. Я даже гонял массовую обработку картинок через php, все летало.

**UPD**

валится все на строчке `$response = $kernel->handle($request)`.

Убрал все следы своего присутствия в конфигах, почистил кэш для продакшена и, на всякий, для дева - ноль реакции.

Comment: очевидно проблема не в symfony. Попробуйте запустить тот же phpinfo(), как он себя будет вести?

Comment: Он ведет себя мгновенно, как и config.php. Консольные команды тоже летают.

Comment: под какой ОС запускаете? возможно надо установить права на папки и файлы

Comment: linux/lubuntu 13.10, там у всей группы есть доступ ко всему, да и не стал бы он из-за отсутствия доступа тормозить и забивать io.

Comment: Скачал версию 2.4.1 с сайта, ничего не трогал, та же ситуация, лог всегда одинаковый (валится на

    ControllerNameParser->parse('controller' => ''web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction'') in /srv/sandbox/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Routing/DelegatingLoader.php line 63

). Мне искать их трекер и создавать там issue?

Answer (score 1):

Сайт Symfony рекомендует использовать не composer, а их установщик.
http://symfony.com/download

По факту, он скачивает один архивный файл со всеми предустановленными зависимостями.

Comment: Если вернуться на два года назад, то там предпочтительней было ставить через композер.

Comment: поддерживаю, и сейчас можно спокойно через composer ставить